# ios) Source exposure in runtime errors in framework

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, frameworks

I wonder why the framework source is exposed when runtime errors occur

The framework is made of Cocoa Touch Framework

Error were artificially caused

Forces a closure that is a nil value

If you know how the source of the framework is not visible in runtime errors, let me know

Comment: if you have sources of the framework, rebuild it with "Generate Debug Symbols" = NO  parameter.

Comment: Also you can try this solution for static libraries: https://gist.github.com/neonichu/1662881

Comment: @peter Andrew Romanov oh! thanks you. It is very good :)